# android app stopped working when button with okhttp3 request clicked

Tags: android, okhttp

I'm making an application with buttons for sound recording and a button to upload the recording file to server. The upload button supposed to call a function containing okhttp3 multipart request, but when i click it the application stop working. I'm really confused because it just exactly the same with the tutorials..

Below is part of the codes related to the upload button. I'm still learning to implement the request properly, please help me understand..

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    buttonnn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonnn);

    buttonnn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
                sendFile();
        }});
    }

private void sendFile() {
    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
    File f  = new File(AudioSavePathInDevice);
    String content_type  = getMimeType(f.getPath());
    String file_path = f.getAbsolutePath();

    RequestBody file_body = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse(content_type),f);
    RequestBody requestBody = new MultipartBody.Builder()
            .setType(MultipartBody.FORM)
            .addFormDataPart("title", content_type)
            .addFormDataPart("uploaded_file",file_path.substring(file_path.lastIndexOf("/")+1), file_body)
            .build();

    Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .url("http://MyServer/thefile.php")
            .post(requestBody)
            .build();

    client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call call, final Response response) throws IOException {
            if (!response.isSuccessful()) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Response error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

The gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion '25.0.2'

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.android_examples.audiorecording_android_examplescom"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 25
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

repositories {
maven {
    url  "http://dl.bintray.com/lukaville/maven"
}
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.6.0'
}
```

edit : i think the php file is correct, because it's working with the original project. but here it is to make the code easier to read.

```
<?php 

$file_path = "images/";

$file_path = $file_path . basename($_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']);

if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'],$file_path)) {
    echo "success";
}else {
    echo "error";
}

?>
```

that's it

Comment: Add the log error of the app.

Comment: @TDG i'm using netbook with 4GB RAM so it is troublesome for emulation, and i try the app immediately on android

Comment: @TDG on closing it's saying "unfortunately app has stopped working" or "app keeps crashing"

Comment: i just changed the onFailure and onResponse to do task to blank, and the app stop crashing. The server successly receive the file too

Answer (score 0):

try changing the onFailure

```
@Override
public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
}
```